# How to group together sequential, timestamped rows in SQL and return the date range for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got an MS SQL 2008 database table that looks like the following:

`Registration | Date | DriverID | TrailerID`

An example of what some of the data would look like is as follows:

```
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:00,54,23
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:01,54,23
...
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:45,54,23
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:46,54,NULL <-- Trailer changed
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:47,54,NULL
...
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 11:05,54,NULL
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 11:06,54,102  <-- Trailer changed
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 11:07,54,102
...
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 12:32,54,102
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 12:33,72,102  <-- Driver changed
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 12:34,72,102
```

As you can see, the data represents which driver and which trailer were attached to which registration at any point in time. What I'd like to do is to generate a report that contains periods that each combination of driver and trailer were active for. So for the above example data, I'd want to generate something that looks like this:

```
Registration,StartDate,EndDate,DriverID,TrailerID
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:00,2013/07/03 10:45,54,23
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:46,2013/07/03 11:05,54,NULL
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 11:06,2013/07/03 12:32,54,102
AB53EDH,2013/07/03 12:33,2013/07/03 12:34,72,102
```

How would you go about doing this via SQL?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the answers so far. Unfortunately, they stopped working when I applied it to production data I have. The queries submitted so far fail to work correctly when applied on part of the data.

Here's some sample queries to generate a data table and populate it with the dummy data above. There is more data here than in the example above: the driver,trailer combinations 54,23 and 54,NULL have been repeated in order to make sure that queries recognise that these are two distinct groups. I've also replicated the same data three times with different date ranges, in order to test if queries will work when run on part of the data set:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempTable](
    [Registration] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DriverID] [int] NULL,
    [TrailerID] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.TempTable
VALUES 
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 10:00', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 10:01', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 10:45', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 10:46', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 10:47', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 11:05', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 11:06', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 11:07', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 12:32', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 12:33', 72,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 12:34', 72,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:00', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:01', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:02', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:03', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:04', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:05', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:06', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:07', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:08', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:09', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:10', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013/07/03 13:11', NULL,NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.TempTable
SELECT Registration, DATEADD(M, -1, Date), DriverID, TrailerID
FROM dbo.TempTable
WHERE Date > '2013/07/01'

INSERT INTO dbo.TempTable
SELECT Registration, DATEADD(M, 1, Date), DriverID, TrailerID
FROM dbo.TempTable
WHERE Date > '2013/07/01'
```

Comment: i think there is a mistake in expected result data :
`AB53EDH,2013/07/03 10:06,2013/07/03 12:32,54,102` shuld be `AB53EDH,2013/07/03 1**1**:06,2013/07/03 12:32,54,102`

Comment: +1 . . . You have working code in your question.  An inspiration to work on it.

Comment: @Amr, how should registrations with NULL Driver and NULL Trailer appear in the summary?

Comment: @8kb: They are a valid combination that should be represented in the results like any other combination.

Comment: @Amr, so in your example, those rows with a NULL value for Driver and Trailer only have one record. In that case, is the start date and end date the same?

Comment: @Amr, scratch that last question. Code in answer has been updated to accommodate NULLs in both values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses CTEs to:

1. Create an ordered collection of records grouped by Registration
2. For each record, capture the data of the previous record
3. Compare current and previous data to determine if the current record
   is a new instance of a driver / trailer assignment
4. Get only the new records
5. For each new record, get the last date before a new driver / trailer
   assignment occurs

Link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8592/2/0)

Code below:

```
;WITH c AS (
-- Group records by Registration, assign row numbers in order of date
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY Registration 
    ORDER BY Registration, [Date]) 
  AS Rn,
  Registration,
  [Date],
  DriverID,
  TrailerID
FROM 
  TempTable
)
,c2 AS (
-- Self join to table to get Driver and Trailer from previous record
SELECT 
  t1.Rn,
  t1.Registration,
  t1.[Date],
  t1.DriverID,
  t1.TrailerID,
  t2.DriverID AS PrevDriverID,
  t2.TrailerID AS PrevTrailerID
FROM 
  c t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  c t2
ON 
  t1.Registration = t2.Registration
AND 
  t2.Rn = t1.Rn - 1 
)
,c3 AS (
-- Use INTERSECT to determine if this record is new in sequence
SELECT
  Rn,
  Registration,
  [Date],
  DriverID,
  TrailerID,
  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT DriverID, TrailerID 
            INTERSECT 
            SELECT PrevDriverID, PrevTrailerID) 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
  END AS IsNew
FROM c2 
) 
-- For all new records in sequence, 
-- get the last date logged before a new record appeared
SELECT 
  Registration,
  [Date] AS StartDate,
  COALESCE (
    (
       SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
       FROM c3 
       WHERE Registration = t.Registration
       AND Rn < (
         SELECT TOP 1 Rn
         FROM c3 
         WHERE Registration = t.Registration 
         AND Rn > t.Rn 
         AND IsNew = 1 
         ORDER BY Rn )
       ORDER BY Rn DESC 
    )
    , [Date]) AS EndDate,
  DriverID,
  TrailerID
FROM 
  c3 t
WHERE
  IsNew = 1 
ORDER BY 
  Registration,
  StartDate
```

Answer (score 1):

try-:

```
DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE (
    [Registration] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DriverID] [int] NULL,
    [TrailerID] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
VALUES 
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 10:00', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 10:01', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 10:45', 54,23),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 10:46', 54,nULL),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 10:47', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 11:05', 54,NULL),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 11:06', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 11:07', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 12:32', 54,102),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 12:33', 72,102),
('AB53EDH','2013-07-03 12:34', 72,102)

SELECT t1.Registration, MIN(t1.Date) AS StartDate, MAX(t1.date) AS EndDate, t1.DriverID, t1.TrailerID
FROM @TempTable AS t1
INNER JOIN @TempTable AS t2
    ON t1.Registration = t2.Registration AND (t1.DriverID = t2.DriverID OR t1.TrailerID = t2.TrailerID)
GROUP BY t1.Registration, t1.DriverID, t1.TrailerID
    ORDER BY MIN(t1.Date)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are still problems with this method. If the same combination of driver and trailer appears later on in time, the query treats them as one group rather than recognising that these are two distinct groups separated by a time period. I've updated the original question to include some more data points to help illustrate this. You'll notice that the combination of 54,23 and 54,NULL for Driver,Trailer is repeated twice, but the results from your query don't reflect that.

Comment: oh, now it's a totally different story, once i made a question very similar to your one, and it yet has to be answered : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853782/sql-get-groups-of-intersecting-dates), i'll be glad to hear any news on this post !

Comment: That's a shame! The only other way I can think of doing this is sequentially using cursors, but with large amounts of data, I've found this can be quite slow and was hoping that if there was a set based method of performing the same task, I might get better performance. We'll see what further developments turn up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses correlated subqueries:

```
with tt as (
       select tt.*,
              (select top 1 date
               from TempTable tt2
               where tt2.Registration = tt.Registration and
                     tt2.DriverID = tt.DriverID and
                     (tt2.TrailerID = tt.TrailerID or tt2.TrailerID is null and tt.TrailerID is null) and
                     tt2.Date < tt.Date
               order by date desc
              ) prevDate
       from TempTable tt
      )
select registration, min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate, driverid, trailerid
from (select tt.*,
             (select top 1 date
              from tt tt3
              where prevDate is NULL and
                    tt3.Date <= tt.date
              order by Date desc
             ) as grp
      from TempTable tt
     ) tt
group by grp, Registration, DriverID, trailerid;
```

The CTE is doing a `lag(date)` on the registration, driverid, and trailerid, producing the previous date for a record.  This is `NULL` at the beginning of a sequence of records.

The subquery then finds the most recent date on a NULL record on or before a given record.  This acts as a grouping variable.  Everything in a sequence has the same `grp` at this point.

The final query aggregates this into the format that you want.

This is a complicated query.  The syntax can be simplified somewhat in SQL Server 2012, using the `lag()` and cumulative aggregation functions.  With those functions, you can follow essentially the same approach.

EDIT:

Ouch.  The above query has a logic error in calculating previous date.  The fix requires assuming that the dates are unique in the data.

The error above is that it looks for the previous date where the triple of columns matches.  Dumb, dumb, dumb.  Because there can be a triple that matches but earlier in the data.  Instead, it needs to get the previous date and *then* see if the triple matches.

The following implements this with an additional join.  It is running [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cd1d/11) on SQL Fiddle.

```
with tt as (
       select tt.*, tt3.date as PrevDate
       from (select tt.*,
                    (select top 1 date
                     from TempTable tt2
                     where tt2.date < tt.date
                     order by date desc
                   ) prevDate1
             from TempTable tt
            ) tt left outer join
            TempTable tt3
            on tt.prevdate1 = tt3.date and
               tt3.Registration = tt.Registration and
               tt3.DriverID = tt.DriverID and
               (tt3.TrailerID = tt.TrailerID or tt3.TrailerID is null and tt.TrailerID is null)
     )
select registration, count(*), min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate, driverid, trailerid
from (select tt.*,
             (select top 1 date
              from tt tt3
              where prevDate is NULL and
                    tt3.Date <= tt.date
              order by Date desc
             ) as grp
      from TempTable tt
     ) tt
group by grp, Registration, DriverID, trailerid;
```

Comment: First off, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. As I've been studying the query and attempting to apply it to my production data, I've realised that unfortunately it doesn't work in all cases. It seems that the query relies on each driver/trailer combo being preceded by another combo (even if it's different) that has its prevDate set to NULL (i.e. this is the first occurrence of that combo in the data). Unfortunately, in the production data, this is not the case as all the combinations can occur multiple times in the same data range.

Comment: @AmrBekhit . . . I do not understand your comment.  This query captures multiple sequences of rows, based on the date, that have the same `registration`, `driverId`, and `trailerId`.  The same triple can appear multiple times, with different dates, and they will appear correspondingly multiple times in the data.  The calculation of `prevDate` determines where each sequence begins.

Comment: I modified your query to work on a subset of the data in the table (I've pasted the query here: http://pastebin.com/9E6a3J00). Try recreating the TempTable using the updated code in the question and with the new table, then run the query. You'll notice that for the groups that fall on 2013/08/03, the groupings are incorrect.

Comment: In fact, even if you just recreate the temp table and run your original query, you'll still see this problem.